# How to redownload Xbox 360 games bought on Xbox one X To Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I bought red dead redemption 1 (Xbox 360 game) on my Xbox one X through Microsoft store. How can I re download it and play it on my Xbox 360. It shows on my Xbox 360 but doesn’t let me play. When I check my HDD for it it says it’s corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If it says that it is corrupted I would delete the game and redownload the game in full on the 360 through the store. Make sure you are signed into the same account that you purchased the game with.

Edit: If you have save data so long as you are only deleting the game application itself, you should not be losing any save data.

Comment: I did that. Reformatted the whole Xbox 360 and then signed in again from a total new account and bought the game
Again but still same. It says it’s downloaded but when I check my HDD it says it’s corrupted. I looked up and found that it may be because of the IP since but I checked and it’s from my own country India and I also changed the locale and language to India. Still no luck. I can play it on my one X but since it’s emulated on it. It’s really buggy

Comment: It's possible that your hard drive might be failing and when the game is being written to your drive it hits a bad sector and keeps failing because of that. Only other way to tell if it is a bad game or Xbox is to test your account and download on another 360. It it fails on the other device then there's something wrong with the game that is on the store for download.